# Reference RSVP hash from inside the same hash

Tags: ember.js, hash

I'm trying to load two different models on the same route, I found a stack overflow that explained I can use `Ember.RSVP.hash()` to get this done, here is what I've done to make it work.

```
model: function(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        flyer: this.store.find('flyer', params.flyer_id),
        images: this.store.find('image', '-Jrgar1tSArUw-_PiJqX')
    });
},
```

As you can see I have hard coded the id of the images record I need to load, this should come from the returned flyer like so `flyer.imagesID`

But when I do that I get an error in the console, this is the stack trace...

```
Error while processing route: flyers flyer is not defined ReferenceError: flyer is not defined
    at model (http://localhost:4200/assets/flyer-creator.js:338:38)
    at EmberObject.default.extend.deserialize (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:32872:19)
    at applyHook (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:55667:32)
    at Object.HandlerInfo.runSharedModelHook (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:53668:22)
    at Object.subclass.getModel (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:53894:21)
    at __exports__.bind (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:55536:19)
    at tryCatch (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:55993:16)
    at invokeCallback (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:56005:17)
    at publish (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:55976:11)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:37026:7
```

Is there a way to access the flyer property that's returned from the hash in the next property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ember.RSVP.hash() is good to avoid encoding the actual promise order. When order is important you could use [promise chaining](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/blob/master/README.md#chaining).

```
model: function(params) {
   var self = this;
   return this.store.find('flyer', params.flyer_id).then(function(flyer) {
     return Ember.RSVP.hash({
       flyer: flyer,
       images: self.store.find('image', flyer.get('imagesID'))
     });
   });
},
```

In your special case you use route dynamic param `params.flyer_id`, so the better way:

- resolve `flyer` in model hook,
- resolve `images` in afterModel hook, based on model.

The reason is that model hook is not fired when you pass flyer model directly to route `{{link-to 'flyer' 'flyer' flyer}}` or `transitionTo('flyer', flyer)`.

```
model: function(params) {
  return this.store.find('flyer', params.flyer_id);
},

afterModel: function(flyer) {
  var self = this;
  // flyer is model already resolved
  return this.store.find('image', flyer.get('imagesID')).then(function(images) {
     var controller = self.controllerFor( self.get('controllerName') );
     controller.set('images', images);
     // or 2 steps: 
     // 1) self.set('images', images) here
     // 2) implement setupController hook, it has controller as param 
  });
}
```

PS If `flyer belongsTo image` you could use promise

```
flyer.get('image')
```

instead of

```
this.store.find('image', flyer.get('imageID'))
```

Comment: How would I reference the image in my template using the afterModel method?

Comment: sorry forget about `self`, see updates, please. `self.controllerFor('flyer').set('images', images);` //=> set 'images' in controller. You could use {{images.someProperty}} in template.

Comment: Cool got it, I started working toward that before your update. It should be noted here I had to generate a generic controller for this to work, as I was getting a stack trace error telling me there was no controller found.

Comment: controller for route should be auto generated, self.controllerFor( self.get('controllerName') ) should work for you without manually controller generation. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#property_controllerName